# Unable to create React typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, fsevents, gyp

Hi I always get the following error while creating typescript based react project, and the project gets created with .js files instead.

I have tried to reinstall the create-react-app utility but did not work.

```
> node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.0.17/fse-v1.0.17-node-v57-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.0.17 and node@8.6.0 (node-v57 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)    > gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.0.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/mpant/my-app/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v57-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/Users/mpant/my-app/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v57-darwin-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/mpant/my-app/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v8.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/mpant/my-app/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v57-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/mpant/my-app/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v57-darwin-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/mpant/my-app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.0.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/mpant/my-app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/mpant/my-app/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.32
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: I see `node@8.6.0` maybe update to node 10 ? the latest LTS ?

Comment: Try also to use a newer version of fsevents. I have `npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.0.17: Way too old`

Comment: So are you using something like this to create your project? `npx create-react-app my-app --typescript` Or are you talking about creating project by hand instead of CLI tool

Comment: I am using npx create-react-app my-app --typescript

Comment: Updating the node version did the trick :). thanks @TitianCernicova-Dragomir

Comment: I recently had a similar issue with node-sass failing to install on node 12 with windows 10 because it failed to find the python binaries, the error looked similar, so I took a shot ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your local create-react-app version to >=2.1

```
npm update -g create-react-app
```

Then create your react app with typescript using below command.

```
create-react-app my-app --typescript
```

Note : using `npx` has a conflict with the global version of installed `create-react-app`. You can also try clearing your npm cache.